# "they have the same" + plural or singular form?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

If I want to say that 2 (or more) balls have the same size, I say:

> they have the same size

But is it also correct to say this?

> they have the same sizes

If it is, when would you use it like this?

Comment: They **are** the same size. If you are talking about more than two items then I would say, "they **are all** the same size."  If they are not the same then it's, "they are different sizes."

Comment: Good point, "are the same size" sounds better. Just out of curiosity is "have the same size" totally wrong or just unnatural/worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases

> the same size

and

> the same sizes

both have the right to exist, and are used to mean different characteristics of the objects which they describe.

If a class of objects can be dimensioned in two or more of ways, for example, pipe segments have the outer (or inner) diameter, wall thickness and the length, then, comparing two pipe segments, you can say

> Those two segments have the same size**s**.

if you mean that **all** dimensions of the two objects measure equal to each other (within some tolerance).

If in some context only specific dimension (like length, for instance) is deemed important, and other dimensions can be ignored, you can say about two pipe segments of two diameters

> Those two segments have the same **size**.

if their length is what's currently important.

When talking of items of clothing, you can say of different pairs of shoes that they all have **the same size**, although no dimension of those complex shapes is the same if carefully measured: the shoe "size" is a marking, classifier, which is only approximately associated with a certain dimension.

Back to your example...

A filled sphere (a ball) has essentially only one dimension - the diameter.  Often enough it is a hollow sphere, and the wall thickness can be taken as the other dimension, but if it is a solid sphere, there is no other dimension.  This way when you only compare one dimension, it is more *natural* to use singular.  But it would not be wrong to say

> The diameter**s** of those balls **are** [all] **the same**.
>   They have the same diameter**s**.

Phrase "the same" when describing a dimension means "of the same value".

Comment: That's a clear explanation! I wasn't actually thinking about sizes in multiple dimensions, but simply whether or not the plural has to / can be used just because there are multiple balls. 
So it seems it's more natural not to use the plural form but it's not incorrect to use it - and if you want to explicitly talk about multiple dimensions then you have to use it.